# How to set dictionary values to null

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if there is a way to put all dictionary values to null (or each elements) ? Because we can't iterate on it if the values has been changed to null.

(I've searched on Stackoverflow before asking this simple question but I didn't find a clear response on this issue).

Regards

Comment: Do you want to empty the dictionary? In that case, just call Clear http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5txwy7s.aspx

Comment: You can iterate over a dictionary if the _values_ are `null`. Not sure why you think you can't. Do you mean that you want to _empty_ a dictionary (so there are no items at all)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
foreach(var key in dict.Keys.ToList())
    dict[key] = null;
```

Important: The call to `ToList()`. This will copy the keys to a temporary list. Otherwise you would get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: ToArray is faster than ToList()

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi: Irrelevant. Have you ever had the case where you had to use one over the other because it was too slow? Also, it's not even true, because their internal implementation is very similar, with the only difference, that `ToArray` has an additional array copy, so if anything, it should be slower.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: `ToArray` create a `struct Buffer` and `ToList` create a `class List`.

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi: So? I repeat my question: Have you ever had the case where you had to choose one over the other because of an actual performance issue that you measured?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: a `class` is reference type and make garbage creation. This is a performance issue.